# Как заполнить матрицу вертикально, python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Дано матрицу n x m. Нужно заполнить вертикально в питоне.
Пример: n = 3; m = 2

```
14
25
36
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вы бы хотя бы свое решение приложили бы

```
m = 5
n = 6

matrix = [[(1 + i + j * m) for j in range(n)] for i in range(m)]

print(*matrix, sep='\n')
```